# In every generation they rise against us - WHO?

Tags: passover, passover-seder-hagada, amalek

We read in the Hagaddah:

וְהִיא שֶׁעָמְדָה לַאֲבוֹתֵינוּ וְלָנוּ. שֶׁלֹּא אֶחָד בִּלְבָד עָמַד עָלֵינוּ לְכַלּוֹתֵנוּ, **אֶלָּא שֶׁבְּכָל דּוֹר וָדוֹר עוֹמְדִים עָלֵינוּ לְכַלוֹתֵנוּ**, וְהַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא מַצִּילֵנוּ מִיָּדָם.

Seemingly, from this it would seem that not necessarily is an enemy of the Jewish people considered to be called "amelek". (Since if we concluded that in every generation, those that stand up to annihilate us are termed Amalek, the hagddah could have said "In every generation Amalek rises against us"

What are some sources for calling the enemies of the Jewish people "amalek" (Such as the Crusaders, Nazis etc)

And, is the Hagaddah referring to anyone or a specific people that stand up against the jews?

Comment: The quote begins by referencing the avot and their struggles but they did not fight against Amalek and their fights weren't even all physical. So the "they" is much more expansive.

Comment: (1) Why are you trying to tie that quote from the Hagaddah to Amalek? (2) You're asking two seemingly separate questions ("sources for calling the enemies of the Jewish people 'amalek'" and "is the Hagaddah [in the quote] referring to anyone or a specific people"). Why not ask them separately? (3) Why not assume that, when it says "שֶׁלֹּא אֶחָד בִּלְבָד עָמַד עָלֵינוּ לְכַלּוֹתֵנוּ", that it is _not_ referring a specific people, but each generation has/had it's own example(s)?

Comment: @TamirEvan ooooh i very much like your third point. Maybe in each generation they have their own, unique enemy.